# How to update document in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read some post how to update document in firebase but it doesn't work for me. User have possibility to add document in his database and he should have possibility to update that entry. Here is my code for now...

```
const form = document.querySelector('#database');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection('database').add({
        field1: form.field1.value,
        field2: form.field2.value 
    });
    db.collection('database').update({
        field2: form.field2.value
    });
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `add` works because you are creating a new document in that collection. On the other hand, when you try to `update`, you have to target which specific document you want to update... updating a `collection` doesn't make sense, you should be targeting a `document`.

Notice the difference in the examples provided in the [the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) for creating a new document in the collection via `add`:

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
db.collection("cities").add({
    name: "Tokyo",
    country: "Japan"
})
```

vs the example to update a particular document:

```
// Set the "capital" field of the city 'DC'
db.collection("cities").doc("DC").update({
    capital: true
})
```

Notice how the `update` targets a particular document? That's what you need to do. I highly suggest you review [the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) for more examples, they're pretty helpful.

**EDIT:**

To edit a document, you need to know it's name... you can either query the collection to discover the name, or you could use the following method of adding a new document, where you get to set the name yourself. In this example, they are creating a new "LA" document, with the name&state&country properties:

```
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
})
```

This way you know the name of your document. By using the `add` syntax, Firebase will auto-generate the name of the new document.

Comment: I read it but is not helpful for me at all, because I am trying to find solution how to select specific document and update it. There is some samples on net but all are for android solution, I need it for web solution. If I have list of documents, how to select some specific document and update it?

Comment: @Magnus Updated the answer to help you out some.

Comment: Ok, and if I want to edit state, not other fields? I am not sure you understand me... User insert his document, with detais (name, state, country) and he wants to change some info, not all document, just specific detail (state). How to choose that specific field and edit it?

Comment: @Magnus The update command is smart enough not to overwrite other fields. If you say `.update({ state: "NY" })` then it will update the `state` to "NY" and leave `name` and `country` untouched.

Comment: Yes, but that should do user, in frontend. When I write that method for field "state" it will write new document, it will not update existing. You are telling me everything what I can find in documentation but there is no explanation how to do that in practice. So, on submit, user will create new document, he can't edit existing document, what he need to do. I need some advice how to do that...